# Unable to parse data from react firebase object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, parsing, react-redux

I have the following functional component which attempts to query data from my firebase realtime database using the `react-redux-firebase` library:

```
export default function Questions() {
    useFirebaseConnect([{ path: 'questions' }])

    const questionList = useSelector(state => state.firebase.data['questions'])

    for (var test in questionList) {
        // THIS WORKS
        var propValue = questionList['12342134234']['content']
        console.log(propValue)
    }
    // THIS RESULTS IN AN ERROR
    var propValue = questionList['12342134234']['content']
    console.log(propValue)

    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, I am unable to access the values of the firebase object directly. When I iterate through the returned object, I am able to view the property names. However, when I try to access these properties directly, (through `questionList[propName]` outside the for loop), my app crashes because the value is undefined.

Logging values to the console, I get:
[image]

I do not understand why doing `console.log(questionList['12342134234'])` works inside the for loop, but then when I do it outside, I get `undefined` and my app crashes. This does not make sense to me.

I am also able to read the object using `JSON.stringify()` but then when I attempt to parse it using `JSON.parse()`, I get `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"`. This is the output for the stringified text:
[image]

Am I going about this the correct way? How would I get the individual property values from this returned object?

> Update:
>   So when I do the following:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        // let parsedList = JSON.stringify(questionList, null, 2)
        // let parsed = JSON.parse(parsedList)
        console.log('BP: ', questionList['12342134234'])
    }, 6000)
```

I get the following output:
[image]
which means it is working once but it is also crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually caused by non-object data, you have to parse the data first.

Try to use `JSON.parse`, then you should be able to access the values directly:

```
let parsedList = JSON.parse(questionList)
console.log(parsedList['12342134234'])
```

**Update**

Seems like it's already parsed, when you get the questionList.

If it works with `settimeout`, then the firebase request can cause the problem, check if the question data loaded:

```
import { isLoaded } from 'react-redux-firebase'`

...

const questionList = useSelector(state => state.firebase.data['questions'])

if (isLoaded(questionList)) {
  console.log('BP: ', questionList['12342134234'])
}
```

Comment: I get `JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"`

Comment: I did exactly as you demonstrated and I still get `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"`. I am not sure why since your explanation makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you need async/await `const questionList = await useSelector...`

Comment: I tried this too but using hooks inside an async function gives me an error, I also update my question with some additional details if that helps

Comment: For testing, you can "simulate" await if you log the data inside a `settimeout`.